# how to add a one time selection button to a php table and selection should change the value of button and database value

Tags: php, html, mysql, button

I am displaying some devices (sensors) data from database. data includes `devices_name`, if there is a warning from device, info about warning, warning accepted or not, who accepted etc. I am successfully getting all the information on a php table. I want add a button to accept warning so that the button press will change the warning accepted to Yes. how to make it - button press should change the data base value, and i should show in my php table and accept button should disable after that.

```
<div>

      <table class="dataTable">

        <th >Date</th>

        <th >Device Name</th>
        <th >Warning Type/th>
        <th >Warning acceted or not</th>
        <th >Who accepted</th>
        <th >Time of acceptance</th>
        <th >Button to Accept</th>

       </tr>


       <?php
       include ("DBconnect.php");
       $conn= mysqli_connect( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $db );

        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
         die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM DeviceData  ORDER BY Datum DESC";

        $result = $conn->query($sql);
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
         while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<tr>
        <td>" . $row["Date"]. "</td>
        <td>" . $row["Name"] . "</td>
        <td>". $row["Warning"]. "</td>
        <td>" . $row["AcceptOrNot"] . "</td>
        <td>" . $row["AcceptTime"]."</td>
//a button to accept the warning
        <td> <button class='btn' >Accept</button> </td>
        </tr>";



      }
      echo "</table>";
      } else { echo "0 results"; }
      $conn->close();
      ?>
      </table>

</div>
```

what I want is pressing the button should disable it, and pressing time should show under Time of acceptance and  Warning acceted or not should change to Yes and  Who accepted will show the name of the person who logged in.

i have database table for all these information. 
please help. any kind of info...

Answer (score 0):

You can POST via the button and then handle the POST on the page load

Would work something like this:

```
//if the accept button was pressed
if(isset($_POST["accept"])) {
    //change the AcceptOrNot value in the database
}

//get stuff from the database

//if it has not been accepted yet, put in the button
if(!$row["AcceptOrNot"]) {
    echo '<form action="yourpage.php" method="post">
              <input type="submit" name="accept" value="Accept" />
          </form>';
}
```

Or you could do it with AJAX if you don't want the page to load again on the button press.

Comment: buttons are formed through a while loop. So i am totally confused,  to choose the exact row in database. I dont need AJAX as page refreshing is fine. I will try.. Thanks

Comment: Oh, right you print many rows. Probably not good to have a seperate button for each then. Unless, you do decide to go with the AJAX approach. You should probably have checkboxes for the warnings and just one button that you can use to accept as many as you want at once.

Comment: checkbox is also fine. Somehow I couldn't figure out any idea so far. !!!